# Trying to append numpy vectors into a matrix using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I'm trying to create a matrix by appending vectors to it.  What I would like to get after the for loop is a matrix that is `(X rows, 10)`.  So if the for loop iterates 15 times the matrix will be `(15, 10)`.

```
m_mat = np.array([])

for stuff in read_bytes(sys.argv[1]):
    one_hot_vector = np.zeros((1, 10))
    one_hot_vector[0, 3] = 1
    m_mat = np.append(m_mat, one_hot_vector, axis = 0)
    #m_mat = np.append(m_mat, one_hot_vector)
    #m_mat = np.hstack((malware_matrix, one_hot_vector))
```

I keep getting errors that the dimensions must match.

Comment: Because your m_mat is initialized to be a size 0 array, and you are appending a size 10 array to it. You will either need to initialize the first array before the loop or create an array of zeros of your final size (if you know), and replace each row during the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.append` (or `np.concatenate`) in a loop is awkward because you have to start with the right 'empty' shape.  You need to understand dimensions to use these functions, especially in a loop.

It also slow, because each append creates a brand new array.

It is faster, and simpler to collect the columns in a list, with regular list append, and create the array at the end with one `np.concatenate`.

The nice thing about `concatenate` is that it takes a list (even long one) of lists or arrays.  `append` takes 2 array, the so called 'base' and the 'addition'.  But under the covers it just use `concatenate`.  So it contributes little except confusion.

---

```
In [19]: np.array([]).shape
Out[19]: (0,)

In [23]: np.append(np.array([]), np.ones((1,10)),axis=0)
   5164         values = ravel(values)
   5165         axis = arr.ndim-1
-> 5166     return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

You start with a (0,) shape array, and try to append a (1,10) array to that on the 1st axis.  One is 1d, the other 2d - they don't have the same number of dimensions!